# Fragments not showing title after application is resumed?

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I have an odd issue which I've never seen anywhere on SO so I've resorted to posting here, hoping I make it clear enough.

I have a simple `SherlockFragmentActivity` as shown further down which contains three fragments which all call `getActivity().setTitle()` in their `onCreateOptionsMenu()` allowing my app to change titles depending on which fragment is visible.

This works as desired, but for some reason (perhaps unrelated) when I exit my application by means of the `HOME` button **occasionally** the title isn't visible upon reopening the application. It seems that should I close my app and reopen it, it's fine but after leaving it for a while the title won't be there when I reopen it.

I have absolutely no idea what could be causing this so any help is appreciated. The layout of my application (relevant to this issue) is a basic splash screen (as an activity) with a loading bar which then opens the following `FragmentActivity`:

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import static java.lang.Math.*;

public class FragmentControl extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    private static final int NUM_PAGES = 3;

    private ViewPager mPager;

    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_control);

        ActionBar action = getSupportActionBar();
        action.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        action.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

        mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPagerAdapter = new FragmentControlAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), NUM_PAGES);
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
        // If this activity wasn't called after a reload
        if((Integer)getIntent().getExtras().get("current") == null){
            // Always start on the middle page, or as close as possible
            mPager.setCurrentItem((int) ceil(NUM_PAGES/2));
        // Otherwise start on the page we left for a smoother experience
        } else {
            mPager.setCurrentItem((Integer)getIntent().getExtras().get("current"));
        }
    }
}
```

Only when the application re-opens to the `FragmentActivity` do I see this issue, when reopening on anything else and navigating to this activity it's fine (as you'd expect).

Any and all help is appreciated, hope I've made it clear.

Oh, and if it matters I'm currently targeting API 17 with minimum support for API 8. The test phone I'm seeing this issue on is a HTC One S - not sure on other devices yet but I'm going to start looking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> occasionally (...) after leaving it for a while

This sounds like your application process is killed in the meantime.

Make sure to save instance state (like what title is displayed) using `onSaveInstanceState` and restore it in `Activity.onCreate` or `Fragment.onViewCreated`.

Comment: But doesn't it opening up back to the FragmentActivity not the Splash screen mean that it wasn't killed? Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @Zackehh9lives No. It doesn't. This is what makes me like this platfom the most. Application state is not tied to process state. You can have one application in many processes or many applications in one process. And when your app is not able to execute code (no process is there to host it) it is **not** dead.

Comment: Ah didn't know that. If I swipe to a new fragment, and the menu changes (changing the title as I mentioned in the original question), shouldn't this set the title again regardless of if the process had been killed? Because swiping between any of my fragments isn't having any effect on the title at all (sorry for the extra question, I'm just quite lost with this).

Comment: @Zackehh9lives Depends on where you call `setTitle`. Most of the `Views` restore their state correctly after process is killed. I would have to check, but I guess `ViewPager` restores page number shown and displays the same `Fragment` for you. Maybe use `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` instead.